# Проверка на шах и мат

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте,помогите пожалуйста с проблемой. Есть следующая задача:

> Напишите программу, которая генерирует
> или считывает шахматную позицию и
> определяет, не находится ли один из
> королей под шахом и не является ли шах
> матом. В программе предусмотреть 2
> варианта ввода исходных данных:
> 1.Шахматная позиция генерируется с помощью датчиков случайных чисел;
> 2.Шахматная позиция вводится с клавиатуры ЭВМ

Скажем, с генерацией и считыванием я разберусь. А вот с определением мата проблема. Уже написал функцию, проверяющую на шаг. Начал писать проверку на мат, уже написал код, который определит, может ли король куда-нибудь уйти из под шага, возможно побив врага. Но потом дошло, что есть ещё такие ситуации, как снятие нападающей фигуры одной из своих и заслон короля от шаха, если это возможно. Сначала думал просто проверить, бьется ли поля атакующей фигуры противника и поля, находящиеся между ней и королём (той же функцией проверки на шах было бы не очень сложно все сделать). Но тут другая проблема, а если шах сразу от нескольких фигур? В общем, я в ступоре. Не знаю даже, что делать. Перебор всех ходов черных фигур вряд ли хорош.
Помогите, пожалуйста, может кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей. Или есть идеи, как красиво её решить.

**P.S. Если кому-то интересно, задачу решил. Без перебора, своим способом, как и хотел. Считаю, что так намного эффективнее, так как при моём способе в худшем случае будет 20 проверок на шах (по-моему...), а если перебором - очень и очень много. Считаю эффективность в проверках на шах, так как они, в данном случае, самые трудоёмкие. (10.02.14)**

Comment: Видимо придется делать в лоб - мат, это шах, от которого нельзя укрыться за следующий ход. Так что придется проверять все возможные ходы.

Comment: DreamChild, вы написали "Во-первых, проверять нужно не все ходы у каждой фигуры, а лишь возможность атаковать конкретную клетку. ... " (К сожалению комментировать под вашей записью я не могу, почему то). По-моему, это и есть то, что я и делаю: проверяю, есть ли возможность атаковать конкретную клетку. Точнее те клетки, которые находятся между королём и атакующей его фигурой, включая её.

Comment: @psix-dev, присоединяюсь к @KoVadim,  мне кажется, что при генерации позиции с помощью датчиков случайных чисел, могут получаться совершенно невообразимые с т.з. шахматных правил (и логики игры) позиции, поэтому без полного перебора  не обойтись.

Кстати, не забудьте проверить, что в случае, когда делаете свой ход, закрывающий от шаха, Вы не открываете одновременно другой удар по королю.

Comment: @psix-dev это не то, что вы делаете. Во всяком случае, в том виде, в каком вы описали это. Насколько я понял, вы хотите проверять, находится ли клетка под боем, "сканируя" все возможные подходы к клетке. Я же имею в виду проверку, находится ли клетка под боем, проверяя возможность каждой вражеской фигуры ее атаковать.

Comment: Я собираюсь сделать генерацию с учетом шахматных правил. А на счет второго совета, спасибо, это я действительно не учел!

Comment: Теперь я, кажется, меняю свою точку зрения в пользу перебора. В голову пришел случай: королю шах, но есть возможность прикрыться, например, ферзём. Но если сместить ферзя, будет другой шаг, от другой фигуры. Это, конечно, можно проверить, но ведь, кроме ферзя, может и другая какая-нибудь фигура закрыть короля. И все такие фигуры придется проверять.... Да, перебор проще...

Comment: В случае, если решил проблему, стоит рассказать о её решении в ответе и по-подробнее.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, проблемы с одновременным шахом от нескольких фигур нет вовсе. Дело в том, что если король находится под шахом сразу нескольких фигур, то единственный вариант спастись - это сделать ход королем. Вариантов уйти может быть 9 (4 "прямых" хода, 4 хода по диагонали и рокировка) Заслонить короля или побить одну из атакующих короля фигур не получится, так как нельзя одним ходом заслонить по нескольким направлениям, также как нельзя одним ходом побить несколько фигур. Следовательно, рассматривать эти варианты защиты имеет смысл только в случае угрозы со стороны одной фигуры.

Comment: Точно, не учел. Но тогда проблема ещё в том, чтобы функция IsCheck узнавала, от скольки фигур шах... Думаю, это не сложно будет. Остаётся вопрос, является ли мой способ проверки на мат нормальным, и знает ли кто более эффективный.

Comment: @psix-dev эмм вы вероятно имеете в виду шах, а не шаг? Кроме того, что такое функция IsCheck у вас, и как она выглядит, я не знаю, поэтому судить о том, что она может, а что нет, можете только вы. Ну а что касается эффективности, то тут тоже нельзя сказать ничего конкретного - об этом можно говорить, только лишь зная непосредственные подробности вашей реализации

Comment: @DreamChild: если мне не изменяет память, рокировка из-под шаха запрещена.

Comment: Проверяю на шах (точнее проверяю на условие, бьет ли поле вражеская фигура) так:  
Иду во всех направлениях по горизонтали и вертикали до первой фигуры. Если это вражеский ферзь или ладья - поле бьется
По диагонали до первой. Если это вражеский ферзь или слон - поле бьется.
также при проходе по горизонтали и вертикали проверяю на короля, если он стоит рядом с полем - оно бьется; а при проходе по диагонали проверяю на пешки, стоящие с нужной стороны (в зависимости от цвета) рядом.

Comment: Сейчас пытаюсь продвинуть идею, на проверку: можно ли побить своей фигурой поля, которые находятся между королём и нападающим, или самого нападающего. Уже написал проверку на побить и на заслонить от ладьи. Немного кода, и всё должно заработать. Но мне не нравится то, что выходит довольно много повторяющегося кода, который через функции не оформишь (много мелких различий). Да и вложенность условий большая выходит, код вправо уходит за экран. Конечно, я постараюсь потом это всё причесать...

Comment: во-первых, вы почему-то забываете о конях. Они ходят не так, как все и могут перепрыгивать через фигуры. Нужно принимать это во внимание. 
во-вторых, вы что-то напутали со слоном по вертикали. Слоны, как известно, ходят диагонально (впрочем, это скорее всего опечатка) 
в-третьих я бы на вашем месте сделал проверку клеток, блокируемых вражеским королём, самой последней. 
в-четвертых, не уверен, что выбранный вами вариант предпочтительнее перебора возможных ходов вражеских фигур

Comment: @psix-dev вложенность условий, размер кода и прочие детали уже зависят от вашей квалификации и опыта. Всё это чаще всего можно привести к вполне корректному виду

Comment: Уважаемые @VladD и @DreamChild, а если память не изменяет мне, то взятие одной из нападающих фигур, может означать уход от шаха несколькими фигурами. 

Кроме того, закрыться от шаха одинокой фигуры, как правило, не удается, если это конь.

Comment: @BuilderC: Я пытался придумать пример этого, но не смог. Попробуете?

Comment: Да мозги уже кипят, поэтому и ошибаюсь с вертикалями и диагоналями. И про коней я не забыл, конечно. Квалификации и опыта совсем мало, я студент 2 курса. А на счет предпочтительности перебора, почему? Допустим у меня десяток фигур (ну или больше), для каждой надо перебрать все поля, куда они могут стать, и после этого каждый раз проверить, остался ли королю шаг. Мне кажется, это менее эффективно - ходов у ферзей, слонов и ладьи может быть не так уж и мало.

Comment: Во-первых, проверять нужно не все ходы у каждой фигуры, а лишь возможность атаковать конкретную клетку. 
Во-вторых, немало фигур не может атаковать конкретную клетку даже теоретически (например 6 пешек из восьми, или один из двух слонов)
В-третьих, фигур может быть существенно меньше чем было изначально
В-четвертых, многие из проверок могут быть очень короткими. 

@BuilderC звучит сомнительно. Присоединяюсь к @VladD

Comment: @BuilderC, уйти от шаха двух фигур можно только если взятие идет королем. в остальных случаях нет.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я же именно это и имел ввиду. Но был не понят.

Comment: @VladD, если слон и ферзь бьют клетку по одной диагонали (с одной стороны), то можно защититься от этого ходом не короля, даже не взяв ни одной из фигур. Ну или взяв ближайшую к нему.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, я могу ошибаться, но вроде бы при этом не считается, что вторая фигура (та, которая дальше) бьёт клетку.

Comment: @VladD, да, что-то я не подумал...

Answer (score 2):

1. Нужно проверить 9 клеток - клетка короля и все вокруг. Какие-либо фигуры противника могут напасть на соответствующие клетки, принять решение - нет шаха, шах, мат или пат (если других своих фигур нету, например).
2. Самый трудозатратный случай когда надо определить можно ли защититься от шаха другими своими фигурами или нет. Для каждой чужой фигуры, нападающей на клетку короля получить все возможные ходы от позиции фигуры до короля. Пройти по массиву этих клеток и определить может ли какая-либо из своих фигур пойти на эти клетки. Если может - шах, если ни одна не может - мат. При определение возможности взятия чужой фигуры предусмотреть взятие пешкой, взятие пешки на проходе.

ну в общем задача в том виде как сформулирована на 90% решает задачу "игра в шахматы", не слабая задача, прямо скажем.

Comment: Ну, как я понял, я примерно так и делаю. Кроме взятия пешки на проходе.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал просто перебором всех возможных ходов из данной ситуации на 1 ход:

1. все возможные ходы белых — удастся ли "съесть" чёрного короля хотя бы одним из вариантов? Да – ситуация, как минимум, шаховая;
2. все возможные ходы чёрных — есть ли хоть одно положение, в котором король не под ударом? Да – таки шах. Нет – мат.

Comment: Перебор - слишком неэффективная вещь, мне кажется.

Comment: Оптимизировать-то можно, но для полноценной шахматной программы, а не в описанной ситуации анализа одной позиции.

Каждая фигура – объект, в котором описаны правила, по которым он ходит. Итерации по всем фигурам, по всем возможным ходам каждой => очередная позиция на доске => ответ на единственный вопрос "под ударом ли король?", или "съеден ли король?".

Max 32 фигуры * max 28 вариантов хода (у ферзя в центре) < 896 ходов всего просчитать. Смартфон справится : )

Comment: Если слово "объект" было связано с ООП, то нет, я пишу на C, так что всё немного сложнее. А на счет "смартфон справится" - да, я согласен, справится. Но у меня задача сделать максимально эффективно...